# Sweater effect shader Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, 2d, shader, game-development

I'm writing some xmas game and found such cool sweater effect https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wjmnh9lIuEM but I have no idea how to realise same for LibGDX, also have no exp with shaders at all. Looks like I need to set texture and increase pixel size. Or its more complex for noob like me and I should go another way?

Comment: It is not trivial for a beginner with shaders. My best guess is that the yarn texture is specially encoded to use two of its color channels for rounding off coordinates, while a third channel is the actual yarn image. So for example, the yarn texture may be 64 "yarn-pixels" wide and tall. In a drawing program, the yarn is made monochrome red. Then each yarn pixel is manually color with increasing shades of pure green from left to right. And again with blue from bottom to top.

Comment: Then the game is drawn to a frame buffer object. Finally the yarn texture and frame buffer's texture are drawn to screen with a shader that uses the G and B of the yarn texture to look up the appropriate pixel from the frame buffer. Then that color is multiplied by the R channel for brightness.